# Laravel 7 - Trying to get property 'task_name' of non-object - Form with various inputs plus multi-image upload

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am trying to test the multiple upload feature of my app but unable to get to that phase as I am stuck on the `Trying to get property 'task_name' of non-object`
I am new to Laravel and have experience uploading form data to the database. This form, however is a bit different as I am attempting to upload an array of images. I am not even sure if I am doing that right. What is stopping me is the form action. Aside from the Laravel error, I am getting something in the console that I don't understand as well. I am using `Route::resource` for my store method which I will post in greater detail below. In the console I notice that it is repeating my tasks route and I don't know if this is normal. Here is the console error:

```
/tasks/tasks?_token=***Token Info Here***_method=POST&task_name=Toilet+repair+&task_priority=3&task_description=dsfsdf&task_assigned_by=Ren%C3%A9+Gomez&task_assigned_to=John+Whitmore&task_to_be_completed_date=2020-09-13&task_status=Pending&task_notes=sdfsdf&imageName%5B%5D=broken-toilet.jpg&imageName%5B%5D=carpet.jpg&imageName%5B%5D=molding.jpg:1 GET http://taskapp.test/tasks/tasks?_token=***Token Info Here***_method=POST&task_name=Toilet+repair+&task_priority=3&task_description=dsfsdf&task_assigned_by=Ren%C3%A9+Gomez&task_assigned_to=John+Whitmore&task_to_be_completed_date=2020-09-13&task_status=Pending&task_notes=sdfsdf&imageName%5B%5D=broken-toilet.jpg&imageName%5B%5D=carpet.jpg&imageName%5B%5D=molding.jpg 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my form in my create.blade.php

```
<form action="tasks" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mb-5">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        @method('POST')
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                id="task_name"
                type="text"
                name="task_name"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Task Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select
                id="task_priority"
                type="text"
                name="task_priority"
                class="form-control"
              >
                <option value>Select a Priority Level</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea
                id="task_description"
                type="text"
                name="task_description"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Task Description"
              ></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                id="task_assigned_by"
                type="text"
                name="task_assigned_by"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Assigned By"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                id="task_assigned_to"
                type="text"
                name="task_assigned_to"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Assigned To"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="task_to_be_completed_date">Due:</label>
              <input
                id="task_to_be_completed_date"
                type="date"
                name="task_to_be_completed_date"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Due: "
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select
                id="task_status"
                type="text"
                name="task_status"
                class="form-control"
              >
                <option value>Select Task Status</option>
                <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
                <option value="Incomplete">Incomplete</option>
              </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="task_notes">Notes:</label>
              <textarea
                id="task_notes"
                type="text"
                name="task_notes"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Notes: "
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <label for="imageName">Image(s)</label>
            <input type="file" name="imageName[]" multiple />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Create Task</button>
    </form>
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

TaskController.php (relevant functions only)

```
 public function create()
    {
        return view('tasks.create');

}
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'task_name' => 'required',
            'task_description' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Create Task
        $task = new Task;

        $task->task_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $task->task_description = $request->input('task_description');
        $task->task_priority = $request->input('task_priority');
        $task->task_assigned_by = $request->input('task_assigned_by');
        $task->task_assigned_to = $request->input('task_assigned_to');
        $task->task_to_be_completed_date = $request->input('task_to_be_completed_date');
        $task->task_notes = $request->input('task_notes');
        $task->task_status = $request->input('task_status');
        $imageName = array();
        if ($files = $request->file('imageName')) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move('imageName', $imageName);
                $imageName[] = $name;
            }
        }
        Task::insert([
            'imageName' => implode("|", $imageName)
        ]);
        // $task->imageName = $request->input('imageName');
        $task->save();
        return redirect('/tasks')->with('success', 'Task Created');
    }
    
    public function show($id)
    {
        $task =  Task::find($id);
        return view('tasks.show')->with('task', $task);
    }
```

and finally, my show.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="/tasks" class="btn bg-purple mb-4">Go Back</a>
    <div class="card p-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <h3>Task</h3>
                <p>{{ $task->task_name }}</p>
                <h3>Assigned On:</h3>
                <p>{{ $task->created_at->format('m/d/Y') }}</p>
                <h3>Assigned To:</h3>
                <p>{{ $task->task_assigned_to }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <h3>Task Description</h3>
                <p>{{ $task->task_description }}</p>
                <h3>Priority</h3>
            <p>{{ $task->task_priority }}</p>
                <h3>Status</h3>
                <p>{{ $task->task_status }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <h3>Due:</h3>
                <p>{{ $task->task_to_be_completed_date }}</p>
                <h3>Notes</h3>
                <p>{{ $task->task_notes }}</p>
                <h3>Images</h3>
                    {{-- @if(count($tasks) > 0)
                        @foreach($tasks as $task)
                            <img src="{{ $task->imageName }}" alt="">
                        @endforeach
                    @else
                        <p>No Images to show</p>
                    @endif --}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can take a look and let me know what I might be doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. If I am missing any files or code, please let me know so I can edit my query. Thank you again in advance.

Comment: You are trying to GET a multipart/form-data server request. Shouldn't that be POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upload an array of images` and `multipart/form-data`

req `POST` form

if you are using `Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');` then add `@method('put')`
so make `method="POST"`

```php
<form action="tasks" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mb-5">
@method('put')
```

and use this so you will not get any error like `Trying to get property 'task_name' of non-object`

```php
$task =  Task::find($id);
```

to

```php
$task =  Task::findOrFail($id);// if task is not present will throw 404 error
```

---

#### one more issue i can see

```php
  Task::insert([
            'imageName' => implode("|", $imageName)
        ]);
```

it should be

```php
 $task->imageName =  implode("|", $imageName);
```

Comment: Thank you Kamlesh and Dimitri. I implemented the suggestions and I now get the following error: POST http://taskapp.test/tasks/tasks 405 (Method Not Allowed)  plus a 500 internal server error. I'm left scratching my head. :)

Comment: Ok. I did that and am still getting an internal server 500 error and when I click the create button, it sends me to /tasks/tasks which is a blank page. No other errror except for the 500 error.

Comment: It is set to true. Where do I look for the logs? It was on since the beginning.

Comment: The form is probably being taken to relative route. Changing form action to `action={{ route('tasks.store')}}` might solve that error

Comment: Thank you user3532758. I am getting another error as a result but I will check tomorrow. I will let you know. It has something to do with not liking that I am using an array, it wants a string. I will keep you posted. Thank you.

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles this problem is solved  so make it mark so another will not try to solve